# Django taggit узнать кол-во объектов, у которых стоит определенный тег

Tags: django

Мне нужно вывести топ популярных тегов, для этого надо узнать сколько раз они используются, как это сделать?

Comment: А вообще код был бы не лишним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно написать запрос по тегам, считая, в скольких объектах он имеется. Это можно реализовать с помощью `annotate`

Не понятно как устроены теги и у каких моделей ои используются, но примерный базовый вариант для 1-й модели

```
qs = Model.objects.values('id', 'tags__id').annotate(tag_count=Count('tags__id'))
qs.group_by = ['tags__id']
qs = qs.values('tags__id', 'tags_count').irder_by('-tags_count').values('tags__id')

Tag.objects.filter(id__in=qs)
```

Для 2х и более будет сложнее

Про generic связи я вообще молчу